# Multiply numbers for loop java returning 0

Tags: java, numbers, return, multiplication

I'm trying to take a number(n) and multiply it by every number before it, enter 4 you get (1x2x3x4) = 24. My code returns a 0. I have an addition just like this that works. Any ideas?

```
public static int multiplyTooNum() 
    {
        Scanner myIn = new Scanner(System.in);          
        int n;
                    
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");    
        n = myIn.nextInt();
        myIn.nextLine();
        int sum = 0;
        
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            sum = sum * i;
        }                   
        
        int result = sum*n;
        System.out.println(result);
        myIn.close();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: initialize `sum` with `1` instead of `0`, the same with `i`. The reason should be clear.

Comment: `for` loops while i is *less than* the inputted value and starts from zero. You should loop from 1 to n, so change the initialization to 1 and the loop condition to `i <= n`.

Answer (score 1):

In multiplication, the accumulated variable is not called `sum`. It is called `product`. The word `sum` is only used in the context of addition.

Now, on with your problem:

If you remember your elementary school mathematics, anything multiplied by zero gives zero.

That's why you are receiving a zero in the end.

So, in order to fix this, you have to initialize your `product` with `1` instead of `0`, and then make your `for` loop start counting from index 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Then maybe i read the first version wrong. I thought it mentioned the fix for both issues.

Comment: @f1sh I provided the fixes as two different alternatives that would solve the problem, while in fact both fixes are necessary.  It is a small thing, but it makes the difference between a correct answer and a wrong answer

Comment: ah, i didnt notice that you listed the 2 things as alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        sum = sum * i;
    }
```

Issue is in this part, you start i from 0, so each time the sum get's 0 and it will be multiplied again. I suggest you to learn debugging and step over in loops to pinpoint the issues.

Comment: `sum` is also 0 in the beginning, which is the second problem.